# NestJs - Ignore Class validation in Class Validator

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I have a DTO. I need to validate user entries against some strings . Those values are coming from ENV file. I got it to work, but I also need to ignore the case.

This is the value from the env file:

```
SEARCH_BY_LANGUAGE="Java,Javascript"
```

This is my version where it works, but it is sensitive to cases:

```
@Expose()
@IsNotEmpty()
@ApiProperty()
@IsIn(process.env.SEARCH_BY_LANGUAGE.toLowerCase().split(","))
targetLanguage: string
```

Problem with this approach is that, java and Java are treated differently.

I have tried to use the @Matches, like this:

```
@Expose()
@IsNotEmpty()
@ApiProperty()
@Matches(`^${process.env.SEARCH_BY_LANGUAGE.split(",")}$`, 'i')
targetLanguage: string
```

But I am getting this error:

> [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor
> '^Java,Javascript$' +14493m

I feel I am close, but cant figure it out.

Comment: Why not force the incoming value to lowercase for the check against the `@IsIn()` decorator using `@Transform()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible approaches for that, the first one is `@Transform()` decorator from [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer), like Jay McDoniel commented above:

> You can perform additional data transformation using @Transform decorator. For example, you want to make your Date object to be a moment object when you are transforming object from plain to class:
>
> ```js
> import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
> import * as moment from 'moment';
> import { Moment } from 'moment';
>
> export class Photo {
>  id: number;
>
>  @Type(() => Date)
>  @Transform(({ value }) => moment(value), { toClassOnly: true })
>  date: Moment;
> }
> ```
>
> Now when you call plainToClass and send a plain representation of the Photo > object,
> it will convert a date value in your photo object to moment date.
> @Transform decorator also supports groups and versioning.

So you would do something like this:

```js
@Transform((value) => value.toLowerCase() })
 targetLanguage: string
```

Your second approach would be to use a [NestJS custom interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) and manually change your payload/data before using it

Comment: Custom interceptor never crossed my mind. And I used it frequently. Great suggestion.